# Entity Framework Code First. Como gerar dois bancos a partir de dois projetos, com o segundo projeto utilizando classes do primeiro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Fala pessoal!

Tenho uma dúvida com relação ao Entity Framework 6.

Tenho dois projetos A e B, sendo A um núcleo compartilhado. Ele possui algumas classes como Pais, Estado, Cidade, Endereco etc.

No projeto B, tenho algumas classes como Candidato, Vaga etc.

No caso, as classes do projeto B referenciam as classes do projeto A, como:

```
public class Candidato
{
    public virtual int IdEndereco { get; set; };
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Tenho dois contextos, um para cada projeto. Cada projeto terá sua própria base de dados.

Quando inicio o projeto, os bancos são criados normalmente para os dois projetos.

O problema é que para todas as classes de A referenciadas por B, são criadas uma tabela no banco do projeto B.

No entanto, essas tabelas só deveriam existir no banco do projeto A.

O banco ficou assim:

A (Pais, Estado, Cidade, Endereco)

B (Pais, Estado, Cidade, Endereco, Candidato, Vaga)

Há alguma configuração no Entity para dizer que as classes de A referenciadas por B não devem ter tabelas criadas no banco do projeto B?

Obrigado.

Comment: Claro que ele vai criar as tabelas, como você quer que seja criada uma relação entre duas tabelas sendo que uma delas nem existe?

Comment: A tabela vai existir, mas em outro banco. No caso, teria que alterar a classe para não ter um relacionamento forte? Tipo: 

class Candidato { public int IdEndereco { get; set; } }

Sem o virtual, nem a variável Endereco

Comment: Com as informações que apresentou é o que eu penso que deveria ser feito, relacionar os Id's sem criar relações reais no banco de dados. Qual a necessidade de manter estes bancos separados? Se é pra ser um banco compartilhado por várias aplicações, eu acho que seria melhor pensar numa solução mais elegante...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se utilizar o [NotMapped] o migration ignora a relação, porém a propriedade endereço sempre virá nula, terá que carregar de outra forma.

```
public class Candidato
{
    public virtual int IdEndereco { get; set; };
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Dessa forma essa propriedade Endereço não viria preenchida na consulta por que esse relacionamento não existe no contexto atual.

Também pode utilizar com fluent (é mais aconselhável pra não poluir sua entidade):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(modelBuilder.Entity<Candidato>               ().Ignore(x => x.Endereco));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Eu utilizaria GUID ao invés de int para o ID já que as relações estão entre bancos diferentes.